# Connected-react-router doesn't work with React 18

Tags: reactjs, redux, connected-react-router

I have encountered a problem when trying to install connected-react-router in my test project on React 18: npm installation fails with an error:

> npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
>
> npm ERR! node_modules/react
>
> npm ERR!   react@"^18.1.0" from the root project
>
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency
>
> npm ERR! peer react@"^16.4.0 || ^17.0.0" from connected-react-router@6.9.2
> or similar packages with

I found information [in the repository of `connected-react-router`](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router) that:

> v6.0.0 requires React v16.4.0 and React Redux v6.0 / v7.0.

So, I have questions: 1) is connected-react-router maintained? The date of last commits is 7 months ago; 2) are there any similar packages to connect router in React 18 project? Or any inbuilt functionality added in React 18?

Of course, connecting React router to Redux store manually is not difficult at all, but I'm interested in ready solutions. Also I have been searching on the topic, but I can't find any info. Thanks in advance for answers.

Answer (score 5):

just put that flag to ignore the old react verison
npm i connected-react-router  --legacy-peer-deps

Comment: Thanks, but just ignoring the dependency version didn't help: I have an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')".

Comment: @RomanKaragodin were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Daniel, no, I was just wondering out of curiosity. On my current work project there's React 17, so it's fine. Perhaps you can try to install an older version of `history`: I read somewhere that it is the main reason of incompatibility.

Comment: @RomanKaragodin you got a package.json that I could use as a starter proj?

Comment: @RomanKaragodin did you fix this issue? I am using react 18 and I can not change its version

Comment: No, I didn't fix that. On my current project it was decided to drop connected-react-router as outdated and implement another solution.

Comment: What did you use instead of connected-react-router?

Comment: Still nothing: we're using React 17 and haven't migrated from connected-react-router yet. But it definitely would not be a problem to implement some custom solution instead - e.g. listen to location change and dispatch some action to save this data in redux store.

Comment: Some alternatives from the internet: https://github.com/lagunovsky/redux-react-router (has similar API), or https://github.com/salvoravida/redux-first-history. Taken from Github issue in connected-react-router https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/issues/578